# how to split by unicode chars in shell

Tags: shell, unicode, awk

using java:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/es.txt");
    List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file, "utf-8");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] arr = line.split("\\u007C\\u001C");
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
```

how can I do it in shell(awk, tr, or sed)?
I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
awk -F\u007c\u001c '{print $1}' es.txt
```

Thanks.

Comment: `awk '{ gsub("\\u007C\\u001C", "\n") } 1'`

Comment: Could you post some part of your source file and corresponding desired output, for sample, please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously, [U+007C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007c/index.htm) and [U+001C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/001c/index.htm) are plain old 7-bit ASCII characters, so splitting on those doesn't actually require any Unicode support (apart from possibly handling any ASCII-incompatible Unicode encoding in the files you are manipulating; but your question indicates that your data is in UTF-8, so that does not seem to be the case here.  UTF-16 would require the splitting tool to be specifically aware of and compatible with the encoding).

Assuming your question can be paraphrased as "if I know the numeric Unicode code point I want to split on, how do I pass that to a tool which is capable of splitting on it", my recommendation would be Perl.

```
perl -CSD -aF'\N{U+1f4a9}' -nle 'print $F[0]' es.txt
```

using [U+1F4A9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm) as the separator.  (Perl's arrays are zero-based, so `$F[0]` corresponds to Awk's `$1`.  The `-a` option requests field splitting to the array `@F`; normally, Perl does not explicitly split the input into fields.)  If the hex code for the code point you want to use as the field separator is in a shell variable, use double quotes instead of single, obviously.

```
PIPE='007C'
FS='001C'
perl -CSD -aF"\N{U+$PIPE}\N{U+$FS}" -nle 'print $F[0]' es.txt
```

Alternatively, if the tool you want to use handles UTF-8 transparently, you can use the [ANSI C quoting facility of Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to specify the separator.  Unicode support seems only to have been [introduced in Bash 4.2](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) so e.g. Debian Squeeze (currently oldoldstable) does not have it.

```
awk -F$'\U0001f4a9' '{print $1}' es.txt  # or $'\u007c' for 4-digit code points
```

However, because the quoting facility is a form of single quotes, you can't (easily) have the separator's code point value in a variable.

Comment: I can't think of a succinct, elegant solution for the UTF-16 scenario.  `iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 | perl -CSD ... | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le` comes to mind, but I cringe a bit.

Comment: you are amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

gawk 4.1.3

```
[root@test /tmp]$ more a
\u8BF7\u5C06\u60A8\u8981\u8F6C\u6362\u7684\u6C49\u6587\u8981\u8F6C\u5185\u5BB9\u
7C98\u8D34\u5728\u8FD9\u91CC\u3002

[root@test /tmp]$ awk -F '.u8981..8F6C' '{print $1}' a
\u8BF7\u5C06\u60A8

[root@test /tmp]$ awk -F '.u8981..8F6C' '{print $2}' a
\u6362\u7684\u6C49\u6587

[root@test /tmp]$ awk -F '.u8981..8F6C' '{print $3}' a
\u5185\u5BB9\u7C98\u8D34\u5728\u8FD9\u91CC\u3002
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

As your question is tagged [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) there is a pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way:

```bash
declare -a out=()
pnt=0
while IFS= read -d '' -n1 char ;do
    LANG=C LC_ALL=C printf -v val %d "'$char"
    (( val == 195 )) && out[pnt]+= &&
        printf -v out[pnt+1] "%s" "${char}" &&
        ((pnt+=2)) ||
      printf -v out[pnt] "%s%s" "${out[pnt]}" "${char}"
done <<<'Il est déjà très tard!'
```

Where submited string containg UTF8 chars and *newlines*, this will create an array of 7 strings:

```
declare -p o
declare -a o=([0]="Il est d" [1]="é" [2]="j" [3]="à" [4]=" tr" [5]="è" [6]=$'s tard!\n')
```

or

```
cat -n <(printf -- "<%s>\n" "${o[@]@Q}")
     1  <'Il est d'>
     2  <'é'>
     3  <'j'>
     4  <'à'>
     5  <' tr'>
     6  <'è'>
     7  <$'s tard!\n'>
```

Where even fields are *separators* and odd fields are *content*.

#### As a function:

```
splitOnUnicod () {
    local -n out=$1
    out=()
    local -i pnt=0 cval
    local char
    while IFS= read -d '' -rn1 char; do
        LANG=C LC_ALL=C printf -v cval %d "'$char";
        ((cval==195)) && out[pnt]+= && printf -v out[++pnt] %s "$char" && pnt+=1 || printf -v out[pnt] %s%s "${out[pnt]}" "$char";
    done
}
```

Then

```
splitOnUnicod myvar <<<"Généralités"
declare -p myvar 
declare -a myvar=([0]="G" [1]="é" [2]="n" [3]="é" [4]="ralit" [5]="é" [6]=$'s\n')

splitOnUnicod myvar < <(printf "Iñès.")
declare -p myvar 
declare -a myvar=([0]="I" [1]="ñ" [2]="" [3]="è" [4]="s.")
```

Where `ñ` as `è` are *separators*, they are in even fields.

```
paste <(printf %s\\n "${!myvar[@]}") <(printf %s\\n "${myvar[@]}")
0       I
1       ñ
2
3       è
4       s.
```